# Jquery Ajax Append input on sending From Data

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, form-data

I have some inputs which wanna send to Controller as *Form Data*, without using the `form`. So I'm using the following js code to get all the `input`s inside a specific element by `id`:

```
var _inputs = $("#price_table").find('input');
```

Then I wanna add another input to `_inputs` after finding (like `$("#input_id")`)But how can I do this? I've tested some functions which added other types (`undefined`) to the array.

Comment: why not you appending other input in _inputs

Comment: @user2875761 I have tries this, but sends `undefined`! I used `push` and `append` methods return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some inspection in browser debugging mode, I found out we need an iterator due to `push` **the same type** for appending to `_input` like this:

```
//we pushed an extra input before into the _inputs array
var _other = $('#div_id').find('input');//which contains inputs
$.each(_other, function (i, inp) {
    _inputs.push(inp);
});
```

I noted that using `_inputs.push($('#Id'));` adds `v.fn.v.init[1]` to the `_input` array instead of array of type `input`!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `$.val()`?

This way you can get the data as

```
var input = $("#input_id").val();
```

as for adding another element,

```
$(div).append( /*input html*/);
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wanna build Form Data to send, your first code returns the value only, and second appends to html element rather than Form Data! We have no `form` element in page.

Comment: Then you can try getting the input data with $.val() en then send it to the controller using $.post or $.ajax (really those are amazing functions)

Comment: You're right my friend :)), But I don't know really why it doesn't work. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
_inputs = _inputs.add('#id');
// then later _inputs.serialize();
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I tried yours but doesn't add any thing to `_input` array! Finally I found a solution and putted that for others :)